# Why does writeRaster in terra give a warning message?

Tags: r, terra

I am trying to rasters by layer using `terra` package. I am using the following code

```
library(terra)

# first create a raster
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10)
# Assign random cell values
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3))
s <- c(r1, r2, r3)

names(s) <- c("a", "b", "c")

writeRaster(s, paste0(names(s), ".tif"), overwrite=TRUE)
```

It works with the following warning message

```
Warning message:
In tools::file_ext(filename) %in% c("nc", "cdf") || isTRUE(list(...)$filetype ==  :
  'length(x) = 3 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

What does this message means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug that you can ignore. It was fixed in the development version that you can install with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')` but it has not made it to CRAN yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
paste0(names(s), ".tif")
```

Actually produces a vector of 3 strings:

```
paste0(c("a", "b", "c"), ".tif")
[1] "a.tif" "b.tif" "c.tif"
```

You probably want only one file, with a name such as

```
paste0(paste(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse = "_"), ".tif")
[1] "a_b_c.tif"
```

To avoid nested paste calls, I suggest looking into the *glue* package

Comment: Actually I want 3 separate rasters.